# Вывод данных из базы с фильтрацией

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 4 таблицы: бренды(ид, имя, кол-во отзывов), товары(ид, ид бренда, ид категории, название, описание), позиции(ид, ид категории, ид бренда, ид товара, название, цена, тип, склад, наличие или предзаказ), категории(ид, категория, родительская категория, является ли категория родительской).
Задача вывести все бренды и их товары с каруселью если больше 1 товара.
Фильтрацию надо сделать через позиции товара по складам, цене, типу, в наличие или предзаказ.

Вопросы:
Как сделать вывод с фильтрацией ? Надо фильтровать через позиции, а выводить бренды с товарами по фильтру позиций, плюс с позиций выводить склады где имеется продукт. Как выводить в карусель если у бренда больше 1 товара подходящего под фильтр?
Можно как-нибудь формировать уникальный запрос для фильтрации сразу sql, если какие-нибудь данные не указаны были для фильтра?

Как формировать такой запрос?
Куда вообще копать? При условие, что данных в позициях больше 100к строк и в товарах больше 10к строк.

Comment: если какие-то данные для фильтрика не укзааны, то не надо это и в запрос пихать.  Берете условный `if (expr)  $sqlWhere .= " and x = y"`. при чем тут карусель вообще не ясно.

Comment: @teran имел виду карусель js вывода продуктов в ней. То есть есть у бренда 1 товар, там она не нужна. Если их более 2, то уже нужна карусель остальных товаров - это я имел виду. 
И как раз хотел узнать можно ли как-то это сделать на чистом sql чтобы не морочиться if ? Так как я описал только пару пунктов фильтрации, так их там 5.

Comment: И у меня плохо с sql, был бы благодарен если бы дали наводку как вообще такие запросы делать? Я имею виду, что фильтровать в позициях и через них раскручивать вывод брендов с товарами подходящими под фильтры. Это ведь делается одним запросом? Ну вложенные хотя есть, join и я не могу понять как и что лучше использовать в данном случае.  Да и материалы по вложенным не смог найти нормального. Если поделитесь где объясняют для тупых, был бы благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Можно сначала получить бренды, где товаров больше одного, примерно так:

```
SELECT b.*, count(p.`ид`) num_products
FROM `бренды` AS b
LEFT JOIN `позиции` AS sp ON sp.`ид бренда`=b.`ид`
LEFT JOIN `товары` AS p ON sp.`ид товара`=p.`ид`
WHERE sp.`цена` > 100 # другая фильрация
GROUP BY b.`ид`
HAVING num_products > 1
```

а следующим запросом уже получать товары с учетом айди полученных брендов

Comment: Проблема в том, что надо сортировать еще по региону, а он находится в позиции, то есть оттуда надо начинать. 
На счет этого немного по другому сделал, с помощью пхп